# create modules and directories by custom spring initializer

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml, initializer, customizing

I want to create custom modules and directories by customize spring initializer but can not insert in `.yml` file

```
{
initializr:
  languages:
    - name: java
      id: java
      default: true
  java-versions:
    - id: 11
      default: true
  boot-versions:
    - id: 2.5.7
      name: 2.5.7
      default: true
}
```